# Piped output wierdness with 'COMMAND | less', FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, freenas, less

I'm using FreeNAS 9.2.10 console, which is based on FreeBSD. I'm trying to pipe the output of commands through less as a pager: `zfs list -v <poolname> | less`.

What I get is the tail of the file - almost certainly not all of it since it starts 3/4 of the way through the alphabetic list at "R". In any case whatever I press to scroll up or down (page down, down arrow, space, enter), I get a page of tildes

```
~
~
~
~
~
~
END
:
```

and can't see the file or page back (page up, up arrow, b, or whatever). I tried using -z10 both directly and via setenv to force a known situation where its page size was << file size, but it didn't do anything different.

What's going on, or what am I derping?

Comment: Could it be that everything goes to stderr?

Comment: Tildes mean that there is nothing to see from what I remember. You can try `-~` option for `less` to get rid of them in case they are added by `less`.

Comment: You can also try `more` instead.

Comment: I tried `more`;  it was even `less` helpful (no puns intended)

Answer (score 1):

Behavior like that generally indicates that the output is going to stderr rather than stdout. You can force it to go to stdout instead by using `2>&1`, like this: `zfs list -v <poolname> 2>&1 | less`.